# How to disable systemctl unit?

Tags: fedora, systemd, automounting

I have a home.mount unit that mounts my home directory to a partition different than what I wish.  Things I have tried:

- Using fstab to override it.  However, fstab does not mount /home unless I type "mount /home" at the command prompt after each boot.
- Masking home.mount unit.  However, after reboot its status shows "masked active mounted": no change in behaviour.
- Disabling home.mount.  However, only unit *files* can be disabled; since I do not know which unit file home.mount corresponds to, I was not able to disable it.
- Deleting home.mount.  However, no home.mount file is found in the whole /.
- Getting status of home.mount to see if it's possible to modify it.  The only file its status references is, /proc/self/mountinfo; and, that is not a modifiable file.

How can I mount my home directory as I wish?  I have Fedora 18.

Exact info, in case someone can interpret something:

```
Id=home.mount
Names=home.mount
Conflicts=umount.target
Before=local-fs.target
Description=home.mount
LoadState=masked
ActiveState=active
SubState=mounted
FragmentPath=/dev/null
SourcePath=/proc/self/mountinfo
InactiveExitTimestamp=Tue 2013-01-01 08:44:59 GMT
InactiveExitTimestampMonotonic=14108083
ActiveEnterTimestamp=Tue 2013-01-01 08:44:59 GMT
ActiveEnterTimestampMonotonic=14108083
ActiveExitTimestampMonotonic=0
InactiveEnterTimestampMonotonic=0
CanStart=yes
CanStop=yes
CanReload=yes
CanIsolate=no
StopWhenUnneeded=no
RefuseManualStart=no
RefuseManualStop=no
AllowIsolate=no
DefaultDependencies=yes
OnFailureIsolate=no
IgnoreOnIsolate=yes
IgnoreOnSnapshot=no
NeedDaemonReload=yes
JobTimeoutUSec=0
ConditionTimestampMonotonic=0
ConditionResult=no
Where=/home
What=mtd0
Options=rw,relatime,rw,rp_size=4096
Type=jffs2
TimeoutUSec=1min 30s
ControlPID=0
DirectoryMode=0755
Result=success
UMask=0022
LimitCPU=18446744073709551615
LimitFSIZE=18446744073709551615
LimitDATA=18446744073709551615
LimitSTACK=18446744073709551615
LimitCORE=18446744073709551615
LimitRSS=18446744073709551615
LimitNOFILE=65536
LimitAS=18446744073709551615
LimitNPROC=1714
LimitMEMLOCK=65536
LimitLOCKS=18446744073709551615
LimitSIGPENDING=1714
LimitMSGQUEUE=819200
LimitNICE=0
LimitRTPRIO=0
LimitRTTIME=18446744073709551615
OOMScoreAdjust=0
Nice=0
IOScheduling=0
CPUSchedulingPolicy=0
CPUSchedulingPriority=0
TimerSlackNSec=50000
CPUSchedulingResetOnFork=no
NonBlocking=no
StandardInput=null
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=inherit
TTYReset=no
TTYVHangup=no
TTYVTDisallocate=no
SyslogPriority=30
SyslogLevelPrefix=yes
SecureBits=0
CapabilityBoundingSet=18446744073709551615
MountFlags=0
PrivateTmp=no
PrivateNetwork=no
SameProcessGroup=yes
ControlGroupModify=no
ControlGroupPersistent=no
IgnoreSIGPIPE=yes
NoNewPrivileges=no
KillMode=control-group
KillSignal=15
SendSIGKILL=yes
```

Comment: from `man systemd.mount`: *mount points created at runtime (independently of unit files or `/etc/fstab`) will be monitored by systemd and appear like any other mount unit in `systemd`. See `/proc/self/mountinfo` description in `proc`(5).* but i dunno what that means - why would they be created at runtime? what might cause it? im looking through it a little more now... seems weird, though. maybe its an automatically generated dependency of some other service or unit or something... seriously, `systemd` is ***mammoth***. maybe its because you did the `mount`, though? didn't you say you did that?

Comment: Fedora 18 is EOL for quite some time. You should update.

Comment: @Jakuje Unfortunately, Fedora 18 was customized for this device.  Even doing `yum update all` bricks the device, because it replaces some package with a version too updated for the device, and it segfaults at next boot.  So updating is not an option.

Comment: not too updated for the *device*, usually, but for the *kernel*, or other non-kept modules. are there weird modules on it? if the device needs special, proprietary drivers you *might* be stuck, but bitching at the vendor can be helpful. just do a *whole* installation - if any.

Comment: @mikeserv The modules on it are not "custom", just standard modules tweaked to take up less RAM, less storage, etc.; I suspect that it is the drivers that are the problem.  The vendor stopped supporting this hardware in US a few years ago, possibly because people could not update past 18.
p.s., when do you sleep?  You posted after I went to sleep, and I posted right after waking up, even before breakfast, and you are also awake already.

Comment: well, maybe i had the terminology confused, but i always thought that drivers were almost all just modules. aren't they loaded as modules most of the time? i slept a little - i was up *late* last night though. my cat woke me up sitting on my face. i dozed off again a little later. im back now.